# Azure, MVC, and Service Worker

Tags: asp.net-mvc, azure, web, progressive-web-apps

I have a simple website where I'm trying to [**Add To Homescreen**](https://developers.google.com/web/fundamentals/app-install-banners/) function to the website. I'm using Visual Studio to code then I host it in Azure.

For some reason, it keep giving me this `Failures: Manifest start_url is not cached by a Service Worker.` every time I audit my website using Lighthouse.

I've make sure that all my page is cache by the service worker.

[image]

I'm not sure if it's my `start_url` or my `service-worker`problem. Below is my code.

`manifest.json`

```
  {
   "short_name": "MY EXPERTS",
   "name": "MYEXPERT",
   "icons": [
    {
      "src": "Images/petronas_logo_192.png",
      "type": "image/png",
      "sizes": "192x192"
    },
    {
      "src": "Images/petronas_logo_192.png",
      "type": "image/png",
      "sizes": "512x512"
    }
 ],

 "background_color": "#FFFFFF",
 "theme_color": "#67BCFF",
 "display": "standalone",
 "start_url": "/Home/Index"
}
```

`AddServiceWorker.js`

```
if ('serviceWorker' in navigator) {
navigator.serviceWorker.register('/service-worker.js').
    then(function (registration) {
        // Registration was successful``
        console.log('ServiceWorker registration successful with scope: ', 
registration.scope);
    }).catch(function (err) {
        // registration failed :(
        console.log('ServiceWorker registration failed: ', err);
    });
}
```

`service-worker.json`

```
 self.addEventListener('install', e => {
 e.waitUntil(
    caches.open('airhorner').then(cache => {
        return cache.addAll([
            '/',
            '/?utm_source=homescreen',
            '/Home/About',
            '/Home/Index',
            '/Home/Contact'
        ])
            .then(() => self.skipWaiting());
    })
  )
});

self.addEventListener('activate', event => {
 event.waitUntil(self.clients.claim());
});

self.addEventListener('fetch', event => {
  event.respondWith(
    caches.match(event.request).then(response => {
        return response || fetch(event.request);
    })
  );
});
```

Comment: Everything here looks good. /Home/Index` is in the manifest, service-worker.js, and in the cache storage. But when I look at your live site the `manifest.json` specifies `/Home` as the `start_url`. That path is not cached offline.

Comment: Hello. I did some changes some minutes ago. If you check back the website, you can see that my `start_url` is included in my `service-worker.js` and also in the Chrome's cache. Despite that, it still gives me fail value for the audit. I also enabled `Bypass user engagement checks` in Chrome.

Comment: I would guess it's an issue with the manifest being listed three times as  `<link rel="manifest" href="/manifest.json">`. Try making sure you only have one version of each asset. You also have the `addtohomescreen` JS file several times.